# How to keep my oven evenly heated

Tags: baking

While baking at 350 yesterday part way through cooking the broiler element came on and burned the top of my cake. Any ideas on why that would happen?

Comment: David, welcome. We need more information such as what type of oven you have, e.g. gas or electric. Does it have both a top and bottom heating element? And any other pertinent details you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

It maybe that you had the oven set to Preheat or Broil instead of Bake. If that's not the case, you may have a problem with the controller for the oven (I have never heard of this happening in older ovens, but with newer electronic/computer controlled models I could see something like that happening.)